# What is rule-based algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm

What's the specific definition of a rule-based algorithm? Are there frameworks that offers rule-based algorithm (MSDN)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean algorithms for "association rule learning", then those are algorithms for automatically discovering interesting relations among variables in large dataset (a typical problem in [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) has a good description for this, including a list of algorithms and also links to implementations. Unfortunately I don't know of any specific implementation in c#.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my professor just gave me the term rule based algorithm and try to find a definition from it especially from Micrsoft

Comment: Well, another option is that your professor is talking about algorithms for [Rule Based Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_system). That's an entirely different thing. See also [@KeithS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248063/what-is-rule-based-algorithm/5248290#5248290) answer above. Maybe you should double-check with your professor.

Comment: So is rule based system similar to an expert system? Then is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx what do Microsoft has to offer?

Comment: Yes, rule based systems are expert systems. The link in your comment above point to a page talking about "Data Mining Algorithms", so more on the line of my original answer. You can see in that page a section called "Association algorithms": that's what I was talking about in my answer. I do recommend that you double check what your professor intended.

Comment: He's sleeping and he mentioned to me last time that it's rete algorithm similar to that one so maybe yes it's this one.

Comment: So, it's rule based systems! The Wikipedia page on [Rete Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) has a link to [NRuler](http://nruler.codeplex.com/): I don't know it, but the web page says it's "a fast production system based on RETE algorithm written in C#": it seems that you can download the source code. Maybe this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

This could have other meanings for other people (you didn;t specify much context here). What comes to mind for me is rules like this:

rule 1: an cat is a mamal

rule 2: a mamal has a tail

combining rules 1 and 2 we can conclude that a cat has a tail. this is called forward chaining.

Things to google for:

- expert systems
- List item
- forward/ backward chainging
- Rete algorithm  Windows
- Workflow Foundation (has a rule engine)

But again, this is what comes to my mind. There maybe other meanings to the phrase 'rule-based algorithm'.

Comment: Is rete algorithm = rule based algorithm? PS: Does it really matter if I really do not accept an answer in my questions since their questions are really not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: The Rete algorithm is an effiecient algorithm that can work out conclusions for systems with large numbers of rules, so I guess that would be yes. Large numbers of rules can become NP-hard. Well the chance of not getting an answer to a straight question here is pretty low. A low AR would indicate either asking questions that are difficult to answer, or not bothering to accept an answer. It doesn't paint the whole picture but it's a useful statistic.

Comment: Windows Workflow Foundation is microsoft technology by the way, your prof may mean that.

Comment: What about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx isn't it similar to rete algorithm/rule based algorithm?

Comment: Hi, not directly. Although you could use datamining to come up with rules to be used in an expert systems (using a rule engine) they are not directly the same. Datamining algorithm let find patterns in data. A rule engine draws a conclusion based on a set of rules. So you could use the found patterns to design your rules, that;s how they relate as far as i can see.

Comment: Assocation Algorithm from Data mining uses rule engine to draw conclusion, am i correct?

Comment: What I said is the other way around,that a datamining finds patterns that can be used in a rule engine. (I don't know the internals of clustering so you could be right here i don't know). The exmple would be an insurance company that mines the claims database and finds th atyoungsters tend to wreck their car. Then that information could be used in an expert system to have a rule that youngstrs do not qaliffy for any discounts.

Answer (score 1):

When I heard "rule-based algorithm", I immediately thought of a "rules engine", which would allow users of your application to customize behavior by specifying conditions and other rules for actions your app performs.

These are not trivial to implement; you're basically creating your own language to be interpreted by your application. MS has a couple of tools, the Business Rules Engine and the Windows Workflow Foundation; I can tell you from experience they are both a [derogatory name for female dog] to work with.

Answer (score 1):

In some programming languages like Mathematica a rule based programm is defined as one that uses replacement rules (replacing parts of an expression by something else) rather than procedural constructs to do something.
This can be very powerful and make some algorithms much simplier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I Also have a post at my blog about what is a forward chain inference engine and how Rete as a pattern matching algorithm works. You can find more detail at http://www.flexrule.com/archives/forward-chain-inference-engine-with-rete/